# How can I import patterns via QR code?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've seen tons of Animal Crossing: New Leaf patterns posted across the internet accompanied by QR codes, implying that there's a way to scan those QR codes in-game to import those designs. However, I can't find any sort of import feature in the game.

How can I scan QR codes in the game? Is it something that I have to unlock?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usage of QR Codes is unlocked at the Able Sisters clothing shop after becoming friends with Sable.  If you've played previous entries in the Animal Crossing series, you might be familiar with this process: you simply chat with Sable at least once a day for a number of days, and she gradually becomes more friendly with you.

As far as I can recall, this is the first game in the series that rewards you for going through this friendship process.

**Update:**  I've been speaking with Sable every day for 10 days, and now the QR machine has been unlocked today (which would have made 11 days if I had to continue). I spoke to her for 10 consecutive days, so I do not know if this will also work if you skip a day.  Lyle and Nook had a short conversation regarding the Able Sisters when I visited them yesterday -- I'm not sure if the friendship process unlocked that but I think it is probably an easter egg.

At any rate, the QR machine looks like a large sewing machine that sits on the back wall near Sable.  When you attempt you interact with it, you will open dialog with Sable.

[image: A screenshot of the Able Sister's shop, with the QR machine in the background.]

Instructions to read QR codes are as follows:

- Select QR Code Machine.
- Tell Sable you would like to use QR Code machine.
- Tell Sable you would like to 'Read a QR Code.'
- Select one of your current designs to be replaced by a new design.
- Line your Nintendo 3DS Camera up with the desired QR Code.
- Confirm that the displayed design is OK.

The displayed design will then become one of your 10 patterns.

Comment: I've been doing a real-time playthrough since the North American release.  I'll update this answer with screenshots of the QR machine and some verified information about the number of days you need to speak with Sable in order to unlock the machine. I've seen conflicting information online concerning if you need to speak with her for 7 or 10 days.  I'm currently on day 8, so I'm expecting to find out more on Wednesday.

Comment: It's been officialized that you must converse with here for ten consecutive days. (http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Sable)

Answer (score 1):

QR Codes are unlocked after presenting one character out of the four main Inhabitants to Sable, the sister working alone. This must be done with 6 presentations and are not needed to be linear visits.

QR; When ever you see a QR on the laptop, screen it with the 3DS while engaged with the QR sewing machine and they will be retrieved.